# TIFF images not showing up in Kendo asp.net Core Grid

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik Kendo Core ASP.Net Grid using telerik.com/2018.3.911 version of the grid.
I have a column that is data bound and pulls down images from a Azure Blob container.
JPG images work fine, but TIF or TIFF do not.
No error, just no image.
If I click the image and tell it to 'open in another window' the image downloads fine, so the path and storage of the image is working correctly.

A working image : 
[image]

A non working image shows:
[image]

Which I thought meant a broken link, but the link is correct and I can download the image just fine.

I am creating the grid with the following code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DDP_WebPortal.Controllers.MobileImage>().Name("gridMobileImages")
                            .AutoBind(false)
                            .Columns(c =>
                            {
                                c.Bound(e => e.absoluteuri).Title("Image").ClientTemplate("#if (absoluteuri != null && absoluteuri != '') {#<a onclick=OpenOriginalImage('#=absoluteuri#') data-toggle='modal' data-target='.ModalFullImage'><img src='#=absoluteuri#' style='width: 100%;border:10px solid #=bordercolor#' class='stopImage' /></a> #} #");
                                //c.Bound(e => e.id).Title("Actions").Width(100).ClientTemplate("# if (id != null && id > 0) {#<a class='btn btn-primary text-center buttonNew' style='background-color:red;color:white;margin-bottom:5px;width: 70px;' onclick='return DeletePicture(#=id#);'>Delete</a><br/><a class='btn btn-primary text-center buttonNew' style='background-color:blue;color:white;margin-bottom:5px;width: 70px;' data-toggle='modal' data-target='\\#ReplacePictureModal' onclick='return OpenReplacePicture(#=id#);'>Replace</a>#} else {#<label></label>#}#").Filterable(false).IncludeInMenu(false);
                                c.Bound(e => e.id).Title("Actions").Width(100).ClientTemplate("# if (id != null && id > 0) {#<a class='btn btn-primary text-center buttonNew' style='background-color:red;color:white;margin-bottom:5px;width: 70px;' onclick='return DeletePicture(#=id#);'>Delete</a>#} else {#<label></label>#}#").Filterable(false).IncludeInMenu(false);
                            })
                            .Events(x => x.DataBound("dataBound"))
                            .Sortable(false)
                            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                            .Input(true)
                            .Numeric(true)
                            .Info(true)
                            .PreviousNext(true)
                            .Refresh(true)
                            .PageSizes(new[] { 1 })
                            .ButtonCount(5))
                            .Scrollable()
                            .Groupable(false)
                            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(false))
                            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(false))
                            .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu).Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
                            .ColumnMenu(menu => menu.Columns(false).Sortable(false).Filterable(false))
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { })
                            .DataSource(source =>
                            {
                                source.Custom()
                                .Transport(transport =>
                                {
                                    transport.Read("GetStopImagesList", "Delivery").ParameterMap("headerFilters");
                                }).Schema(schema =>
                                {
                                    schema.Data("imgList");
                                    schema.Total("imgList.length");
                                });
                            })
        )
```

**Update 12/1/19**

It looks like this is a browser issue. The site renders *correctly* in Edge but not Chrome (Wow!?).

Here is an extremely useful site to see how your browser handles different TIFF upload/link formats.

https://www.alternatiff.com/howtoembed.html